# What does this assignment do?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I was going through a friend's code, and he has the line:

```
dist=${dist:?Must set dist environment variable}
```

What is this line doing? How will it be evaluated? Is there any documentation for this type of assignment?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `man bash` explains it quite well — or find [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the online Bash manual.  Just enter `man bash` at the terminal prompt and search on `:?` and you will find:

> ${parameter:?word}
>  **Display Error if Null or Unset.**  If
>   parameter is null or unset, the expansion of word (or a message to
>   that effect if word is not present) is  written  to  the  standard
>   error and the shell, if it is not interactive, exits.  Otherwise, the
>   value of parameter is substituted.

#### Example

Let's run that command when `dist` is unset:

```
$ dist=${dist:?Must set dist environment variable}
bash: dist: Must set dist environment variable
```

Thus, just as the documentation says, the fact that `dist` is unset causes the error message to be displayed.

Now, let's assign a value to `dist` and run the same command:

```
$ dist=1
$ dist=${dist:?Must set dist environment variable}
$ echo $dist
1
```

Since `dist` is assigned a value, no error message is display and the value of `dist` remains unchanged.

Comment: Thanks... Makes sense :)

Comment: Note that you could also use `: ${dist:?Must set dist environment variable}` without doing the self-assignment.